# Excel PUT to API endpoint failing with bad request

Tags: excel, powerquery, put

I'm trying to duplicate an Insomnia POST request to an API endpoint in Excel. I believe I'm close but I'm obviously missing something in the Excel Power Query request.

Here is the working CURL request from Insomnia:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://url.... \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <<TOKEN VALUE>>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{ "start":"2023-11-29", "end":"2023-11-29" }
```

And here is the Power Query request.  Note that I'm pulling value for the data and token from named ranges in the workbook.

```
let
    Token = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Token"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    FromDate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FromDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    ToDate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ToDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    headers = [#"Authorization"="Bearer "&Token,#"Content-Type"="application/json"],
    postData = Json.FromValue([start = FromDate, end = ToDate]),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://url...", [Headers=headers, Content=postData]))
in 
    Source
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery can only do a GET or a POST. When `Content` is provided it will be POST, otherwise GET.

Try updating this line:

```
postData = Json.FromValue([start = FromDate, end = ToDate]),
```

To:

```
postData = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue([start = FromDate, end = ToDate])),
```

`Json.FromValue` returns a JSON object, `Text.FromBinary` will convert it to a string.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I'm including the Content data to shift it to a POST vs. GET.  However, I believe there is some other issue with the definition of the request/payload in Power Query vs. the CURL request.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, your question title threw me with `PUT` and I missed the `POST` in your curl example. Updated answer above to wrap `Text.FromBinary(...)` around your `Json.FromValue(...)`.

Comment: Thanks again Sam.  I see the issue with my original message and changed the PUT to POST.